# Google Spreadsheets API (Java)

Tags: java, google-sheets, gdata

I'd like to update a spreadsheet with numeric values which are computed by a simple java program.
It's not goign to be an Android app or anything, just plain-regular java.

The problem is the program is quitting on me saying the account is invalid.
But the provided credentials are 100% valid - i copyed them out of eclipse and pasted them into the gmail login form - they work..

The class (which is the basic class out of the api tutorial):

```
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class MySpreadsheetIntegration {
  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {

    String USERNAME = "abc@gmail.com";
    String PASSWORD = "123";

    SpreadsheetService service =
        new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
    service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    // TODO: See other portions of this guide for code to put here...
  }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:660)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:397)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:364)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:319)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:303)
at MySpreadsheetIntegration.main(MySpreadsheetIntegration.java:17)
```

I'm wondering is this even possible using the api w/o android sdk and stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Google Spreadsheets API uses OAuth as Authorization Protocol to its services (in this case API). Read the section on [Authorizing Requests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests) in order to understand how your application can get authorization and access the API.

Also, please consider this **warning** from Google:

> **Warning:** The use of `ClientLogin` as an authorization mechanism is strongly discouraged. Before using this mechanism, please thoroughly
>   consider using OAuth 2.0 with a stored refresh token or OAuth 1.0a
>   with a stored access token.

Comment: Thanks, my problem now is there is no java snippet, just .net

Comment: If you read carefully, there is a tab on the top right hand corner of the code that says "Java". So you can toggle between Java and .NET.

Comment: Sorry either I am blind or there is none for Java regarding the topic 'Performing OAuth 2.0'

Comment: Well, the code is clear that it is *assumed* that you can just "paste" (for lack of better word) the code to Java and fix imports and various compile errors.

Comment: It's not that easy for me to refactor the code...
the OAuth2Parameters - Class becomes com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthParameters ??
What are the right attributes to set id, secret and uri
And OAuthUtil has no static methods at all...

I just really can't understand why they don't give us a java snippet - after all it's needed for all the android apps wishing to use the gdata api..

Comment: Least I found this http://soatutorials.blogspot.co.at/2013/08/google-spreadsheet-api-connecting-with.html

Comment: @kitty, You pretty much figured it out. Congrats! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to use Oauth. But in order for the authentication without Oauth to work, you have turn on `lessSecureApps` in your google account security settings(the account used for the attempted login above).

To turn on `lessSecureApps`, go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps